# Angular 17 SSR setting status on Response doesn't work despite using InjectionToken for REQUEST and RESPONSE

Tags: angular

**I am aware that the server.ts isn't included in dev mode. This is not the problem. This happens in production as well.**

I've defined the tokens in `libs/sdk/src/lib/injection-tokens/ssr.ts`:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export const REQUEST = new InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST');
export const RESPONSE = new InjectionToken<Response>('RESPONSE');
```

I then provide these in `apps/my-project-name/server.ts`:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'node:path';

// NOTE: Have to import tokens from my SDK library or the service injecting the tokens can't access them since server.ts is app-specific and not available in any libraries
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '../../libs/sdk/src/index';

import bootstrap from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(browserDistFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y',
    
    })
  );

  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [
          {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl,
          },
          {
            provide: REQUEST,
            useValue: req,
          },
          {
            provide: RESPONSE,
            useValue: res,
          },
        ],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();
```

I then try to inject the `RESPONSE` token in `libs/sdk/src/lib/services/application-manager.service.ts`:

```
import { RESPONSE } from '../../injection-tokens/ssr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SDKApplicationManager {

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response,
  ) {}

  ...

  get isServer() {
    return isPlatformServer(this.platformId);
  }

  setServerResponseStatus(status: number) {
    
    if (this.isServer) {
      this.response?.status(status);
    }
  }
}
```

And ultimately set the token in `404.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class LibFourZeroFourComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private applicationManager: SDKApplicationManager,
  ) {
    this.applicationManager.setServerResponseStatus(404);
  }
}
```

I then build the project for production and run `node dist/apps/my-project-name/server/server.mjs` which starts the server. I navigate to `http://localhost:4000/404`, but the status of the SSR:ed response for the 404 is 304, not 404, as seen in this picture:

[image: image of status 304 instead of 404 in network inspector]

What am I doing wrong?